# Android ant script with latest sdk(3.0 or later)

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I have written ant script with Android 2.2 and 2.1 OS and it was working fine.

I have updated SDK to 3.2 and when I tried to run it giving error as "pre_setup.xml" not found. I have searched in that path and that file is not available.

Can anyone have knowledge in using ant script with 3.0 or later OS?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try regenerating a new copy of build.xml using android.bat found in the android sdk -> tools directory. Makes sure to create a backup copy of your old file first.

under \android-sdk\tools\

```
android.bat update project -p "path to project file"
```

Then port any changes from your old build.xml into this new one.
(You may find you don't need to port anything if you hadn't made any changes to the old one)

Comment: Thanks for you reply Jeff.

I tried by update and copy the targets with old build.xml file. But I dont know what are the things needs to copy and what to reject.


First I have created build.xml by copying from android_rules.xml and edited the file to my automated targets.
When I update there is no file with that name and if i copied everything from old to new one then getting error as cannot find pre_setup.xml.

Please help me on this.

Comment: can you post a copy of your old build.xml file

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply Jeff. I solved this by updating to new xmls and targets.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If my answer helped, can you mark it as the solution please